# issues with wordpress theme and Elementor repeating text blocks on page prior to the featured image/menus

Tags: wordpress, elementor

i am using a wordpress theme (industryup) and running into an issue where on all pages except the main page, the page text is being repeated three times. Twice at the top above the featured image and menus, and then once more in the correct place, integrated below the menus. I did not make this website but am trying to resolve some issues. I can only edit these pages with Elementor and have tried manually moving the text blocks (on any editing page inside wordpress, the text is only appearing the once)with some absolute positioning, and can get it to the correct placement, but upon saving and loading up the site, I then get the three copies of the text overlaid on each other. I have inspected the code in chrome and the issue seems to be that there is a  then there are 2 identical <div data-elementor-type="wp-page"..> with identical id´s followed by  etc css code and then inside a div with a "content" id, the third, correctly placed block (again with the same id as the other two).

Removing those two blocks in the inspector resolves the issue on the local copy, but as I cannot access the html inside wordpress, I am stuck as to how to resolve this. I have switched themes to check, and the issue does not reproduce on the other themes I have tried. Any ideas?